# Which form file is being used currently? Registration doesn't work

Tags: theme, form-key

After a heavy upgrade to 1.9.2.2 and re-downloading all modules, running supee-6788-toolbox and downloading a new version of the theme, I still run into problems.

In the renderd registration page I can't find `form_key` at all.
So I thought I simply add:
`<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`
to the file `app/design/frontend/default/em0121/template/customer/form/register.phtml` since it didn't contain the form key.

Then deleting cache, reloading page but the formkey is still not showing up in the HTML code.

A search for `sudo grep -r -i 'customer.form.register.newsletter'` only yielded two findings and the default version contains the form_key already.

> app/design/frontend/default/em0121/template/customer/form/register.phtml:                    getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml:                    getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>

Is it possible that my theme doesn't use the register.phtml if someone clicks on register?
How can I find out which form phtml file is currently used on a page I'm looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter this template: `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Since Magento introduce persistent mode some of templates related to customer info have been moved to persistent directory.

Hope this help,

Comment: Perfect - stumbled around until I saw your post. This Upgrade is really annoying me :-S   
Thank you very much. :)